Why does ASP.NET Core Web API not recognize when a user is logged in when passing a bearer token in the request header?
I set up a basic ASP.NET Core 8 Web API controller using AspNetCore.Identity.MongoDbCore package to connect to a MongoDB collection, and added a /api/user/{username} endpoint.
Program.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using MongoDB.Bson;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var settings = new DatabaseSettings
{
    ConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING") ?? builder.Configuration.GetSection("Database")["ConnectionString"],
    DatabaseName = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Database")["DatabaseName"],
    CollectionName = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Database")["CollectionName"]
};

builder.Services.Configure<DatabaseSettings>(options =>
{
    options.ConnectionString = settings.ConnectionString;
    options.DatabaseName = settings.DatabaseName;
    options.CollectionName = settings.CollectionName;
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddBearerToken(IdentityConstants.BearerScheme);
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationBuilder();
builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<User>().AddApiEndpoints();
builder.Services.AddIdentity<User, Role>()
    .AddMongoDbStores<User, Role, ObjectId>
    (
        settings.ConnectionString,
        settings.DatabaseName
    )
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<UserService>();

builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.MapIdentityApi<User>();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

UserController:
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly UserService _userService;

    public UserController(UserService userService) =>
        _userService = userService;

    [HttpGet("{username}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Object>> Get(string username)
    {
        var user = await _userService.GetAsync(username);

        if (user is null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        bool isLoggedInUser = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
        Console.WriteLine(isLoggedInUser);

        return new {
            user, 
            isLoggedInUser
        };
    }
} 

UserService:
public class UserService
{
    private readonly IMongoCollection<User> _collection;

    public UserService(
        IOptions<DatabaseSettings> DatabaseSettings)
    {
        var mongoClient = new MongoClient(
            DatabaseSettings.Value.ConnectionString);

        var mongoDatabase = mongoClient.GetDatabase(
            DatabaseSettings.Value.DatabaseName);

        _collection = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<User>(
            DatabaseSettings.Value.CollectionName);
    }

    public async Task<User?> GetAsync(string username) =>
        await _collection.Find(x => x.UserName == username).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}

I then create a next.js front end and added a login page and a /{username} page
Login function:
'use client'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';

const Login = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const router = useRouter();

useEffect(() => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  if (token) {
    router.push('/'); 
  }
}, [router]);

const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  setError('');


    const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5109/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
    });

    if (response.ok) {
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
      localStorage.setItem('token', data.accessToken);     
      router.push(`/`); 
    } else {
      setError('Login failed. Please check your username and password.');
    }
};

/{username} function
const UserDashboard = ({ params }) => {
  const { username } = params;

  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUser = async () => {
      const token = localStorage.getItem('token'); 

      if (!token) {
        console.error('No token found in local storage');
        return;
      }     

      try {
        const res = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:5109/api/user/${username}`, {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`, 
          }
        });
        if (res.ok) {
          const data = await res.json();
          console.log(`Requested Username: ${username},  Is Logged In User: ${data.isLoggedInUser}`);
          setUser(data.user);
        } else {
          console.error('Failed to fetch user data, response not OK');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Failed to fetch user data:', error);
      }
 };

When I check the requests to the API, I could see that it's passing the bearer token, but both the browser console and the .NET console print out that the user is not logged in.
How can a user log in properly?

You don't log in to an API, as you do to a web site; each call is always separate, independent, stateless. You get the user information in the bearer token - e.g. as a ClaimsPrincipal with its claims - but there's no concept of "being logged in" .....

@marc_s thanks for clarifying! The point is, if I require auth for /{username} and try to access it after logging in on the front end, I can't access /{username} even when passing the bearer token.

Possibly a typo but; your code saves the token to local storage as accessToken but retrieves it as token.  What happens if you call the API directly using an HTTP client (such as Postman) do you get the same unauthenticated error?

@Peppermintology thanks for pointing that out! It was a typo, but even when it was fixed I still got the same error, somebody ended up giving me a solution. Going to post it now.

Somebody ended up helping me out with this.
Instead of using [Authorize] on the UserController I need to use [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Identity.Bearer")].
This made the token I send during the request get accepted and authorizing the user if it matched.
I am not sure if this is the best way of doing it, any insights would be appreciate it.
